How to print from a parallel loop
How can I print from a loop with OpenMP parallel execution? I am hoping to avoid critical code or similar which (I hear) can really slow down the execution.
Additional complication: it seem that on the cluster computer which I ran my code on, I can only print from the master thread (id=0). So I tried the following code. It mostly works, but when a worker thread writes to a stringstream concurrently with the main thread reading it, it can lead to an abnormal behavior.
ADDED: 1. The order of output doesnt matter. 2. Since my job will be terminated after 48h, while possibly still unfinished, I can't wait with printing till the end of the loop computation.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int nthreads=10;
  omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
  vector<stringstream> ss(nthreads);
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
  for(unsigned int i= 1; i<=100000;i++){
    int id=omp_get_thread_num();
    if(id==0){
      for(int idi=0;idi<nthreads;idi++)
        if(ss[idi].tellp()>ss[idi].tellg()) cout<<ss[idi].rdbuf();
    }
    // DO WORK,
    if(some condition) ss[id]<< some outcome...
    // MORE WORK
    ss[id]<< more outcome
  }
  return 0;
}


What do you need to print? Does it need to be printed in a certain order? Would it be less work to print it one one thread? Could you compute what needs printing using a thread-safe data structure and then print what's needed?

You can just print from each thread within a parallel region. What exotic kind of cluster do you use that can only print from the primary thread? You should not confuse MPI (where output might be limited to rank 0) and OpenMP. Writing to std::cout using the operator<< is thread-safe. If you require a consistent output without random interleaving, you should just put the output into a critical region. As long as you only put the minimal necessary code into the critical region, it will not slow down your execution.

Besides the obvious issues resulting from the unsynchronized access to ss, you introduced significant performance issues with your code pattern. Calling omp_get_thread_num() in each iteration is inefficient and unnecessary. Due to the static schedule, each thread needs to execute the same number of iterations. This makes the code sensitive to load imbalances. Since you add extra code for the primary thread, you introduce a permanent imbalance and all other threads will need to wait at the end.

The standard simple solution requires C++20. First observation is std::osyncstream from <syncstream> header:
osyncstream(std::cout) << my_line << "\n;

But if you can use C++20, then <format> will be available too:
std::puts(std::format("{:s}\n", my_line).c_str());

C IO functions like std::puts acquire an internal lock on every invocation.
If C++23 is available too, you can use <print>:
std::println(stdout, "{:s}", my_line);

The latest standard requires that std::print and std::println too, acquire a lock on the output stream before printing. But since it's relatively new, that guarantee is subject to quality of implementation.
Last resort for optimization would be to define a spin lock using std::atomic and lock+unlock on every call. It would be faster than a mutex, but I don't illustrate it now.

std::stringstream is NOT thread-safe. You cannot have one thread write to it at the same time that another thread is reading from it. You MUST serialize concurrent access to it, such as with a std::mutex or other synchronization means.
